# How to address HTML files with name same as folders?

Tags: html, css

I want to add a News section in my site with this address: mysite.com/news

There must be a "News" folder to contain each file like this: mysite.com/news/2021

But when I try to address news.html file (without .html extension), it opens "News" folder (and shows 403 error)

How to addresses the "News" HTML file (without mentioning .html), instead?

Comment: Look into mod_rewrite and "pretty urls"

Answer (score 0):

You need an HTML file with the file name `index.html` in your news folder.

So requesting `mysite.com/news/` (and likely `mysite.com/news` will redirect you to `mysite.com/news/`) will return the same response as `mysite.com/news/index.html`.

On your host it sounds like the default behavior for request to `[something]/` folder will be to return the list of files - except if you have that `index.html` file in the folder.

An example of the same behavior: `https://www.google.com/index.html` is the same as `https://www.google.com/`.

Comment: @MojtabaArmstrong can you mark this answer as the correct then?